# What's the difference between new Function and Function

Tags: javascript

It's quite common to see codes using `new Function`, instead of simply `Function`. I want to understand why, what exactly the `new` operator is doing here.

What's the difference between these two?

```
var y = new Function("a", "alert(a)")
var x = Function("a", "alert(a)")
```

Comment: No difference in this case.

Comment: So, disregarding this case, in what case there would be a difference?

Comment: There is no difference with `Function`. [It's defined to behave the same either way.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-constructor) "*When `Function` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initializes a new Function object.*"

Comment: `String` and `Number` pretty much, ... `Boolean`

Comment: It is a technique used in some constructors where if it is invoked without `new`(ie `this` is the global object, then it self invokes as a constructor)

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, thanks guys. I was curious because I saw most people using `new Function` in codes. So the `new` operator is pretty much a waste of digits there.

Comment: https://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2019/06/25/difference-between-calling-a-function-with-new-keyword-and-without-new-keyword-in-javascript/

Answer (score 7):

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> The `Function` constructor creates a new `Function` object. In JavaScript every function is actually a `Function` object.
>
> ...
>
> Invoking the `Function` constructor as a function (without using the new operator) has the same effect as invoking it as a constructor.

Since functions are actually objects in Javascript, it is possible to call them both via standard invocation syntax and the `new` operator (which instantiates a new object of type `Function` in this case).

What that last line I quoted from the docs is saying is that doing `Function()` is *identical* to calling `new Function()`.

### tl;dr

There is no difference.

Comment: How does something so fundamental not have a squillion upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that when you invoke the function with a new keyword it creates a new 'this' empty object for your function and you can set properties on that inside your function. Also the return value from your `new`-ly called function will be `this` if you do not return something else.

With no new keyword there's no new empty 'this' object so if you are using that inside it will error out.

You might not be using `this` at all in your function so you may see no differences at all.

p.s.: One problem might be that if you are using `this` and you invoke without the `new` kw. the this will be the global this inside the fn. - and in a browser environment that will be the `window` object... so you will be setting props on that instead of on a plain new empty obj.